# Implementing a "remember me" log in system using cookies or sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to implement a "remember me" feature on a website I am currently working on, so that when a user closes the browser and open it again, he will still be logged in with the same user.

What i currently have is a log in page that creates a session when the user logs in. What I want to do is to create a cookie that saves information about the user that allows me to identify him.

Now there are a few thing that I need your help about:

1. I don't want to save any sensitive information in the cookie, such as passwords or even  a username. What i though to save is the session ID created when he first logged in, and save it in a table on MySQL database. Is that a good idea, or is there something better that i can save on the cookie?
2. After I implement the "remember me" feature, will I still need to use sessions? What I mean is, that the website have the option to use it without a user, so of course on every page of the website I will have to check if the user have a cookie stored. If he does I will automatically log him in, but should I do it using a session? isn't it a duplicate that I use both cookies and session for the same purpose, and of course do it for every single page of the website.

By the way I am developing the website using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't really matter. Only I would refrain from reusing this value as a session id again.
2. Yes, you will still need sessions, unless your site is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the md5 of the cookie in the database...but just remember. If a user has multiple devices you get a cookie for each device.

If you don't clean your table once in a while it's going to contain lots of data!